# Why Swift doesn't type inference to Any when put multiple type item in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, types, type-inference, anyobject

there are two situation make me confuse when develop swift 2.2 by using Xcode 7.1, please see the example below, thanks

First, when import Foundation, I declared an testArray which contains two item, an Integer type 1 and a String type "hello", my question is why Swift type inference testArray to Array(NSObject) instead of Array(Any)

```
import Foundation
let testArray = [1, "hello"] 
print(testArray.dynamicType) //testArray is Array<NSObject>
```

Second, when i remove import Foundation, the code below can't be compile, the error message is "Type of expression is ambiguous without more content", my question is why Swift not type inference to Array(Any) in this situation, thanks for help

```
let testArray2 = [2, "world"]
print(testArray2) 
//can't compile, error message = "Type of expression is ambiguous without more content"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
/// The protocol to which all types implicitly conform.
public typealias Any = protocol<>
```

`Any` is just a protocol that all types implicitly conform to – it's not a concrete type itself. Swift cannot infer an array of non-concrete types, which is why it fails to infer `Any`, but succeeds with `NSObject` (`Int` can be bridged to `NSNumber`, `String` can be bridged to `NSString` – and they both inherit from `NSObject`, which is a concrete type).

For example, consider this:

```
protocol Foo {}
struct Bar:Foo {}
struct Baz:Foo {}

let arr = [Bar(), Baz()] // error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Because `Foo` is a non-concrete type, Swift cannot infer an array of it. You have to explicitly tell the compiler what you want its type to be:

```
let arr:[Foo] = [Bar(), Baz()]
```

You'll also get the same behaviour with `AnyObject` (as it's a protocol that all *classes* implicitly conform to – but still not a concrete type):

```
class Qux {}
class Fox {}

let a = [Qux(), Fox()] // error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

let a1:[AnyObject] = [Qux(), Fox()] // no error
```

*Why* Swift is unable to infer an array of non-concrete types is most likely due to the existing limitations of non-concrete types in the language – currently concrete types are required for most non-trivial operations. [See this great Q&A for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

But to be honest, you should really be thinking more about whether you *actually* need an array of `Any`. I cannot think of a single practical application of having an array of `Any`, as because everything implicitly conforms to the elements, they must be guaranteed to do nothing (you can't call a specific method on something that could be anything). Sure you can type-cast, but what's the point in getting back the type safety that you threw away to begin with?

You should always be as type specific as you can. You could build a wrapper for your values – this could either be a simple `struct` to wrap a couple of properties, or a [type erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure) in order to wrap non-concrete types in a pseudo concrete type. At the very least, you should consider creating your own protocol that your array elements conform to.

Comment: Last two paragraphs raise the most important points here.  And honestly, `NSObject` (or `AnyObject` which wouldn't work here but I see it used all the time) isn't that much more specific than `Any`.

Comment: @originaluser2 your explanation is really helpful, thanks a lot

Comment: @c41ux Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it won't auto recognize array of `Any`

it will work if you define it as

```
let testArray2 :[Any] = [2, "world"]
```

the `Foundation` library imports the `NS API`, which automatically converts the `2` to `NSNumber`and `"world"` to `NSString`, converting it automatically to array of `NSObject`

Comment: 1. Answer: Funny, he asks why and you only say because it is so. 2. Answer: If you use `import Foundation`, `2` is `Int` and `"world"` is `String`. Just because there is no native Swift type that can be found (who knows why it does not recognize `[Any]`) it takes the `[NSObject]`.

Comment: @iGodric, hey, you are wrong.1.  look at his error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more content`, It can't auto recognize it because thats how the compiler works. 2. an array of `NSObject` must contain `NSObjects` . if you will do `import Foundation` and do the next code `print(testArray[0].dynamicType)
print(testArray[1].dynamicType)` the output will be `__NSCFNumber` which is NSNumber (and not Int) and `_NSContiguousString` which is `NSString` and not String. thanks for the `Funny` comment.

Comment: To 1. Yes, but an explanations saying "that is how the compiler works" is no explanation. To 2. That what you said is correct, but you are making assumptions in my comment, which I did not say. Yes in that particular case when importing Foundation and creating an array with multiple types `2` is `NSNumber` and `"world"` is `NSString` but only because the inferred type is `[AnyObject]`. But importing `Foundation` does not automatically convert `2` to `NSNumber` per se, that is what I am trying to say. Your answer can be misleading. My first comment may sound to harsh.